# Одинарная кавычка в текстовом поле php

Tags: php, sql, input

Есть текстовое поле с именем nickname. Из него значение передается в базу данных.

```
$insert = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO kos (nickname,reason,game_class,Eternal) VALUES ('".$_POST[nickname]."','$_POST[reason]','$_POST[game_class]','$_POST[Eternal]')");
```

Но если значение содержит одинарную кавычку, то выводит ошибку. Неверный sql синтаксис.

Comment: Скажу больше, у вас неверный php синтаксис.

Comment: Что в нем не так?

Comment: SQL injection у вас. Гуглите, информации уйма. А ещё разберитесь с одинарными и двойными кавычками в запросе.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас гляну.

Comment: читайте раздел справки про подготовленные запросы и биндинг параметров

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php в частности внимательно читать раздел про экранирование и sql-инььекции

Answer (score -1):

Кавычки и прочие опасные символы нужно экранировать перед отправкой в запрос.
Как пример:

```
$name = str_replace ( "'", "\\'" , $_POST[nickname]);
$insert = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO kos (nickname) VALUES ('$name')");
```

То же самое касается остальных полей. У вас в запросе открытая уязвимость к SQL-инъекции
https://habr.com/ru/post/148151/

Comment: А если я сделал подготавливаемый запрос, то нужно экранировать символы, как у вас в примере?

Comment: `if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO kos(nickname,reason,game_class,Eternal,trickster) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"))) {
     echo "Не удалось подготовить запрос: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
if (!$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $_POST["nickname"],$_POST["reason"],$_POST["game_class"],$_POST["Eternal"],$_POST["trickster"])) {
    echo "Не удалось привязать параметры: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Не удалось выполнить запрос: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

$stmt->close();
`